# Calculate the center of mass of a solid 3d polyhedron made of discrete triangles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, physics, computational-geometry, polyhedra

I am writing a physics simulator. The idea is that you load *any* 3d model into it and it simulates collisions.

(I am aware of the difficulties with colliding concave polyhedra, that's a different issue)

We can assume that the polyhedron is solid, closed-surface, but it may or may not be concave, and in general we may not make assumptions about the topology of the object. It is made up of air-tight connecting triangles. We can also assume the shape has uniform material/density.

My approach thus far:

1. Calculate the area for each triangle. (array of weights)
2. Get the center of each triangle. (array of 3d vectors)
3. Piecewise, multiply the resulting arrays from step 1 and 2. This leaves us with an array of weighted 3d vectors. (you could inline step 1 to 3 in a single loop of course)
4. Sum the array of weighted 3d vectors into a single 3d vector, then piecewise divide it by the count of triangles. We now have a center of mass.

But my physics teacher had the following comment on that: "So all polyhedrons are hollow?". He said that doing it this way would only work for hollow polyhedra, but he could not tell me how to do it for solids. I have tried searching this issue but it's left me completely stumped. Could you help?

My second approach, while technically possible, would be very, *very* slow. The testing (step 2) would be done with raytracing and checking wether the surface normal coincides.

1. Generate a random point
2. Check if it is inside the polyhedron, reject if not inside.
3. Repeat a couple of thousand times
4. We now have a point-cloud of the polyhedron, so just calculate the average point.

Comment: You could decompose the solid polyhedron into solid tetrahedra etc.

Comment: @AnginaSeng oh, that's smart! Now I just need to find out how to do that. Thanks for the tip, perhaps you have some papers on the matter? I searched a bit but could only find descriptions of tetrahedralization is, and Delaunay, but that requires that the points inside the body are there already.

Edit: found something! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TetGen